new syntax (indentation) doesn't allow if statement
Here is my code. The idea is that the grades go from 0-5 and it cannot go higher, thus the if command.
Highlighted in the code is the part that apparently is not allowed anymore (grade > 5)- I get a syntax error that says: "This construct is not allowed under -new-syntax."
I have just started learning scala and have tried googling the answer but havent found anything
def overallGrade(project: Int, eBonus: Int, part: Int) =
  var grade = project + eBonus + part
  if (*grade > 5*) {
    grade = 5
  }
  grade
 end overallGrade


What should I do to fix it?
No answers on google that I could find

Out of curiosity: if you are not using the new syntax, why are you turning on the new syntax?

You don't need the parentheses in your if statement:
object GradeCalculator:

  def overallGrade(project: Int, eBonus: Int, part: Int): Int =
    var grade = project + eBonus + part
    if grade > 5 then
      grade = 5
    grade

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    val projectScore = 4
    val eBonusScore = 1
    val participationScore = 2
    val totalGrade = overallGrade(projectScore, eBonusScore, participationScore)
    println(s"Final Grade: $totalGrade")

end GradeCalculator

Output:
Final Grade: 5

Try on scastie.scala-lang.org

You could also write it without a var field:  val grade = project + eBonus + part
if grade > 5 then 5 else grade

Thanks for the answers! After reviewing more online and thoroughly reading the error messages, the if command had changed completely, so it wasn't the x > 5 that was wrong but the whole command. Indeed there is no need for brackets anymore, and now it works perfectly. As for why I changed syntax, we are using the newest one for school and apparently, it updated overnight on my IDE which came as a shock.
